# EditText.setText() gives index out of bounds

Tags: android, android-edittext, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm having an error I can't seem to wrap my head around.  I'm writing an app that allows the user to send text from an `EditText` to a `TextView`.  If the user makes a mistake, the user can hit the space key to bring the most recent text sent from the `EditText` to the `TextView`.  This works sometimes, but other times, it gives me an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

textInput is an EditText, back1,2,3 are the three most recent strings (with back1 the most recent)

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    if(count==1&&before==0&&s.toString().equals(" ")){
        textInput.setText(back1);
    }else if(s.toString().equals(back1 + " ")){
        textInput.setText(back2);
    }else if(s.toString().equals(back2 + " ")){
        textInput.setText(back3); //causes error if back2 > back3
    }

    textInput.setSelection(textInput.getText().toString().length());
```

The above code checks if the user hit the space key, and if so, what to do with it.  If the user pressed space on an empty EditText, they get the last thing they sent.  If they hit space again, they get the next to last thing they sent, and so on.  This is still a bit rough, but I hope you get the idea.

The OutOfBounds exception comes from taking a large item in the `EditText`, hitting space, and setting the `EditText` to a smaller string.  I assumed it was because the cursor is at the end of the `EditText` and could no longer be there when the text got smaller, so I tried adding `textInput.setSelection(0)` right before the `setText()`.  That didn't help.  I also tried setting the `EditText` to `setText("")`.  That didn't work either.  If I comment out the lines of `setText(back#)`, everything works fine.

An example:

A user types in "hello", "hi" and "hey" in that order.

back3 = hello, back2 = hi, and back1 = hey.

Hitting space once will set the EditText to "hey"

A second tap will crash, since the `setSpan(3...4) ends beyond length 2`, presumably because back 1 is larger than back2.  It is supposed to set the text in the `EditText` to "hi"

Comment: I did not read the whole question, but should the line textInput.setSelection(textInput.getText().toString().length()); not be textInput.setSelection(textInput.getText().toString().length() - 1);?

Comment: No, the setSelection() works as expected when going from a small->large.  Besides, the error is more than one off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the `TextWatcher` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html):

> ```
> public abstract void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
> ```
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> This method is called to notify you that, within `s`, the `count` characters beginning at `start` have just replaced old text that had length `before`. **It is an error to attempt to make changes to `s` from this callback.**

(My emphasis.)

You should use `afterTextChanged` instead if you want to change the text more in response to an existing change. Even in this case, your handler will be called re-entrantly when you change the text from `afterTextChanged`, so use an extra precaution to make sure you won't get into an infinite loop, such as something like this:

```
public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {
    static boolean is_reentrant = false;

    if (!is_reentrant) {
        is_reentrant = true;
        
        try {
            // do stuff
        } finally {
            is_reentrant = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this exact snippet, but something like that will make your code only run if it's not already running. You don't need to worry about thread-safety in this case, because it's only being called from inside the same thread.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what s was.  I was thinking it was a new string copy of the text in the EditText.  I didn't think it was the actual object of the text in the EditText.  Is it the actual text object in the edit text?  Either way, moving it to afterTextChanged seems to be working.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know whether it's the actual object, or a copy that's processed further after onTextChanged returns, but changes to `s` *are* reflected in the contents of the `EditText`.